# Creating a Team ReSharper Settings File based on Defaults

Tags: resharper

I read how ReSharper uses the different layers of settings files as per https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/help/Sharing_Configuration_Options.html

So I want to set up a new file for my team, I add a new Blah.sln.DotSettings file at the root of by solution alongside Blah.sln.

When I do this, the file is empty.  How to I create this file with the ReSharper defaults in place?

For example, if a developer changes 'Setting A' from 'Value 1' to 'Value 2' at their machine level, because there is no entry for 'Setting A' in the team file, their machine level setting wins.  I need the original 'Setting A' line in the team level file to overrule their machine level settings

How do I get those default values in the team file in the first place?

I'm having such difficulty doing something that seems so simple that I think there's something I'm missing.

**Update 1**

If at my machine level I change all the settings I'm interested in so they are no longer at the default value, then I go to the team level and set each one back to the default value at that level, that gives me the explicit lines for each of those settings in the team level file.  Then if I clear out the machine level line, I still have those lines at team level which I can check in and share with the team.  I think this will work, it just doesn't seem the right way to go about it.

Answer (score 0):

ReSharper will only save settings that are different to the defaults, to prevent bloating settings files. And due to the hierarchical nature of the settings files, this manifests as not saving if a value in a lower layer is already set to that value.

So, if I change a value in the global settings to a default value, it doesn't get written to the global settings file. If I change a value in the shared team layer, but it's already set in the global settings file (or in the defaults), it doesn't get written to the shared team layer.

What you can do is to use the "Copy Settings To" command in the "Manage Options" dialog. This will give you a list of layers you can copy to, and will copy the settings from the currently selected layer. It will also allow you to choose which settings to copy. This will allow you to copy settings from the default layer, or the global settings layer to a team shared layer.

I've added a feature request to make it easier to set up team shared settings. Please track and vote: [RSRP-444671](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-444671).

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I looked at this, but when I select 'Copy Settings To' it looks like it should let me select something, but the only option I get is "Code Inspection" and below that is "Excluded Files".

I notice that I can do 'Copy To' on a 'level' (e.g. This Computer) or a DotSettings file that has been created under that level.  It also looks like I can copy 'to' the 'File' or 'Level'  is that where I am going wrong?

Comment: The idea is that you export settings from the currently selected layer. So you should have "This Computer" selected, and can export any settings from that layer to the team shared settings. However, AIUI, it looks like it's only exporting what's set in that layer, and since each layer only stores the deltas with the layer(s) below, the "This Computer" layer will only hold the changes to the defaults. You can export this to the team shared, and override them, but someone can set a new default in their "This Computer" and it will be applied, just for them, and not shared.

Comment: I think I'm following you, but the thing I want to copy is the defaults.  Say for example some guys have set "don't use var" at machine level, I need a line at team level saying "use var" to override that, but because "use var" is the default, I can't get that line in the first place.  Am I perhaps trying to make it do something that it's not designed to do?

Comment: Hmm. I don't think that's possible. I think you can only export the changes. I'd strongly recommend commenting on the [YouTrack issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-444671), so the dev team can understand the scenario and requirements.